# Blowup of non-singular varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, blowup, birational-geometry

How to construct a blowup $f$: X $\rightarrow$ Y between non-singular quasi-projective varieties?
This is an exercise from Shafarevich "Basic Algebraic Geometry 1".

I want to construct for any $n \geq$ 2 a regular birational map $f$: X $\rightarrow$ Y between $n$-dimensional quasi-projective varieties having an exceptional divisor $Z \subset X$ such that $f(Z) \subset Y$ has codimension 2.

Now: how to use properly the local systems of parameters in $\xi \in Y$ point of the blowup?

I have also problems to define X, with a right use of local systems of parameters, as a subset of $Y x \mathbb{P^{n-1}}$.